# Why do we need to put const at the begining of the function GetMax?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename Type>
const Type& GetMax(Type& value1,Type& value2)
{
    if(value1 > value2)
        return value1;
    else
        return value2;
}
template<typename Type>
void DisplayComparison(const Type& value1,const Type& value2)
{
    cout<<"GetMax("<<value1<<","<<value2<<") = ";
    cout<<GetMax(value1,value2)<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    int Int1 = -102, Int2 = 2001;
    DisplayComparison(Int1,Int2);

    double d1 = 3.14,d2 = 3.1416;
    DisplayComparison(d1,d2);

    string Name1("Jack"),Name2("John");
    DisplayComparison(Name1,Name2);

    return 0;
}
```

`const Type& GetMax` ... is `const` necessary? If yes why? 
and if I write like this--> `const Type& GetMax(const Type& value1,const Type& value)` what those two `const` are doing? :(

Comment: All this and more is explained in any [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: That `const` is not qualifying the function itself. It qualifies the return type. Same goes for the potential `const` you mention for that parameters, they would qualify those parameters' type. Member function qualifiers come at the very end, like `void foo() const`.

Comment: You're over-complicating it, just return `Type` and not `const Type&`

Comment: @acraig5075 Those two aren't necessarily equivalent. Some types are not copyable and others are expensive to copy. In this case, the function is returning a reference to one of the arguments. Changing the return type would drastically change the function's usage.

Comment: So If I put a const at the begining of the function especially in this case it means that the return type can't be modified right?

Comment: `const T &` means you can't use that reference  to modified the referred object. It doesn't necessarily mean that it can't be modified. It could still potentially be modified using a different non-const reference in another part of your code.

Comment: Ohh yea I got it ! Thank you @FrançoisAndrieux !

Comment: also note that returning a non-const reference to a member breaks encapsulation, in that case you could as well make the member public.

Comment: If there is no duplicate Q&A, these comments should be potential answers....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to put forth a few points about const so that it is clear when and what can you use as required:

Case 1: `GetMax(const Type value1)`

Here value1 is a local copy, I can think of a couple of points

I can think of a few reasons:

1) When someone reads the code and see `const Type value1`, they know that `value1` should not be modified in the body of the function.

2) The compiler will tell you when you try to modify `value1` in the body of the function. Therefore, adding `const` can prevent mistakes.

3) However, there is another difference in C++11. A constant object cannot be moved from, as a move operation modifies the object. Therefore, you can only make a copy of `value1` in the function body and cannot move from it.

4) Also, if this is a class type, you cannot call non-const members functions on a const object.

Case 2: `GetMax(const Type& value1)`

We don't know how `value1` is used outside the function, so we want to protect it from being modified.

Case 3: `const Type& GetMax()`

Talking about the `const` before the function, means it will return a `const` reference to `Type` (here `GetMax`)

Take this example:

```
Class xyz;
Type& t = xyz.GetMax()           //This is INCORRECT
const Type& tc = xyz.GetMax()    //This is OKAY!
```

So, to sum up, you do not "need to use" `const` unless you have such requirements as mentioned above, although it might be good practice to do so in a few situations.